# Problem with finding the limits for double integral.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Hello i am doubting myself that i am finding the right limits for a problem so if someone can verify my approach i will be thankful. So i have $$\iint_D (xy)dxdy$$ a domain is $D= (y=x^2, x-y+2-0)$. From the equation $x-y+2=0$ i find that $y = x+2$ so that should be my upper limit for $y$ and my upper limit should be $y=x^2$ after that i substitute $y$ with $x^2$ in $y=x+2$ and i get $x^2=x+2$  so the roots $x_1 = 2$ and $x_2=-1$ so those should be my limits for x. In the end i have : $$\int_{-1}^{2}\int_{x^2}^{x+2}(xy)dydx$$ and the problem is i don't got the right answer. Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Your bounds are correct. You have probably done the evaluation wrong.

Comment: @quasi i fixed it look again it was writing error or they are still wrong ?

Comment: @Parcly Taxel Ah ok thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bounds are fine. So, you should get that\begin{align}\iint_Dxy\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy&=\int_{-1}^2-\frac{x^5}{2}+\frac{x^3}{2}+2 x^2+2x\,\mathrm dx\\&=\frac{45}8.\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much i am doing the arithmetic wrong. You are getting the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

$I = \int^2_{-1}\int^{x+2}_{x^2}xydydx = \int^2_{-1}x\frac{(x+2)^2-(x^2)^2}{2}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int^2_{-1}(x^3+4x^2+4x-x^5)dx$

$I = \frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{4x^3}{3}+2x^2-\frac{x^6}{6}\bigg]^2_{-1} = \frac{45}{8}$